# Get multi-line v-textarea with v-stepper-items

Tags: vuetify.js

I have two `v-textarea` elements. One is shown on step 1 of a `v-stepper-items`, the other one is shown on page 2. Both shall be rendered multi-line. But only the one that is on the active step when loading the page is multi-line.

I noticed that when I change something in the sourcecode that does not trigger a full page reload, and step 2 is being active at that point of time, the rendered multi-line property will change from step 1 to step 2. So it seems only the `v-textarea` of the step that is active when loading the page will be multi-line.

How can I force **all** `v-textarea`s being rendered multi-line, regardless of their `v-stepper-items` activity?

vuetify 2.6.14

Answer (score 0):

My colleague has found a solution for it. He added a method `step ()` to the view that is automatically called by the stepper when the step / page changed. Also, he added a `:key` boolean variable called `hasUpdated` to the `<v-textarea>` elements. `step ()` now triggers:

```
this.hasUpdated = !this.hasUpdated
```

for each `<v-textarea>` and thereby triggers the correct rendering of the vertical size of also the hidden `<v-textarea>`.